# android serialno as regular expression

Tags: androidviewclient

I get error:
Regular expression not supported as serialno in ViewClient

when I have:

```
D:\work\testing\avc>adb devices
List of devices attached
192.168.56.102:5555     device
```

I have tried

```
adb tcp 5555
adb connect 192.168.56.102
```

which run fine and adb shell also connects fine but AVC will complain and error out.

Regards,

Miten.

Comment: You are not showing the command line used with the **AndroidViewClient** script. If you specify `192.168.56.102` it is a regexp, try escaping the dots: `192\.168\.56\.102`

Comment: I think I tried the dot escape but I already opened issue on your site and workaround.  I think you are doing some regex search for . as well as setting .* as serialno etc.  Please take look at issue#65 I created.  Sorry I will see if I can revert things to give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

The built in String functions should work by themselves. isRegularSerialNumber() could just be

```
boolean isRegularSerialNumber(String pinNumber) {
String regularString = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}";
return pinNumber.matches(regularString);}
```

Also, it looks like you're maybe grabbing the input string from serialText right after you make it visible. Could your problem be in grabbing the text before the user has made any input?